# Javascript groupingDishes code explanation

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I encounter the problem of grouping Diches.
Problem is as follows:
you are given a list dishes, where each element consists of a list of strings beginning with the name of the dish, followed by all the ingredients used in preparing it. You want to group the dishes by ingredients, so that for each ingredient you'll be able to find all the dishes that contain it (if there are at least 2 such dishes).

Return an array where each element is a list beginning with the ingredient name, followed by the names of all the dishes that contain this ingredient. The dishes inside each list should be sorted alphabetically, and the result array should be sorted alphabetically by the names of the ingredients.
For

```
  dishes = [["Salad", "Tomato", "Cucumber", "Salad", "Sauce"],
            ["Pizza", "Tomato", "Sausage", "Sauce", "Dough"],
            ["Quesadilla", "Chicken", "Cheese", "Sauce"],
            ["Sandwich", "Salad", "Bread", "Tomato", "Cheese"]]
```

the output should be

```
  solution(dishes) = [["Cheese", "Quesadilla", "Sandwich"],
                      ["Salad", "Salad", "Sandwich"],
                      ["Sauce", "Pizza", "Quesadilla", "Salad"],
                      ["Tomato", "Pizza", "Salad", "Sandwich"]]
```

I able to write a code but it was not efficient and have bugs then I found this solution:

```
    var a = {};
    for (var i=0; i<dishes.length; i++) {
        for (var j=1; j<dishes[i].length; j++) {
            a[dishes[i][j]] = (a[dishes[i][j]] || []).concat(dishes[i][0]);
        }
    }
       // can't understand what happening below.
    return Object.keys(a).sort().filter(function(b) {
        return a[b].length > 1;
    }).map(function(b) {
        return [b].concat(a[b].sort());
    });
```

I know the first part where he making object and adding key as ingredient and values as dishes but I can't understand what he doing after it. its working but my javascript is not that good. Can someone please explain what happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote:

> I know the first part where he making object and adding key as ingredient and values as dishes

OK, so we can start with the object that the first part creates, which (for the example input) is:

```
{
  "Tomato":   ["Salad", "Pizza", "Sandwich"],
  "Cucumber": ["Salad"],
  "Salad":    ["Salad", "Sandwich"],
  "Sauce":    ["Salad", "Pizza", "Quesadilla"],
  "Sausage":  ["Pizza"],
  "Dough":    ["Pizza"],
  "Chicken":  ["Quesadilla"],
  "Cheese":   ["Quesadilla", "Sandwich"],
  "Bread":    ["Sandwich"]
}
```

So we have as keys the ingredients and as corresponding values a list of dishes that have these ingredients.

> ...but I can't understand what he doing after it

First it extracts a sorted list of the ingredients with `Object.keys(a).sort()`. This sorting is done because the challenges says *"...and the result array should be sorted alphabetically by the names of the ingredients"*. This evaluates to:

```
["Bread","Cheese","Chicken","Cucumber","Dough","Salad","Sauce","Sausage","Tomato"]
```

This array of keys is then filtered to only include those ingredients that have a corresponding array value that has at least 2 dishes. This is because the challenge says *"...all the dishes that contain it (if there are at least 2 such dishes)."*. The filter condition is that `a[b].length > 1`, where `a[b]` is the array of dishes for ingredient `b`. After this filter is executed, we end up with this list of ingredients:

```
["Cheese","Salad","Sauce","Tomato"]
```

Note that the removal of ingredients (that are only used by one dish) does not break the sorting order -- it is still alphabetically sorted.

The next step is to build the final array structure, which should be an array with 4 inner arrays, and where each inner array starts with the ingredient, and is then followed by the list of dishes that have it. For this we use `.map` to map each ingredient `b` to such an inner array.

For a given ingredient `b` it first creates an array with only that ingredient: `[b]`. Then this array is combined (concatenated) with the array of dishes for `b`. That other array is `a[b]`. Before that merge happens, that second array is first sorted. This is because the challenge says *"The dishes inside each list should be sorted alphabetically"*. This is done with `a[b].sort()`. The concatenation of `[b]` and `a[b].sort()` is done with the `.concat` method.

#### Inspecting values

You can go through each step yourself by breaking down the code in more separate statements and logging intermediate results. It will also help to have more descriptive variables names (instead of `a` and `b`). For instance like this:

```js
function solution(dishes) {
    var mapIngredientToDishes = {};
    for (var i=0; i<dishes.length; i++) {
        for (var j=1; j<dishes[i].length; j++) {
            mapIngredientToDishes[dishes[i][j]] = (mapIngredientToDishes[dishes[i][j]] || []).concat(dishes[i][0]);
        }
    }
    console.log("After first step, mapIngredientToDishes = ");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(mapIngredientToDishes, null, 2));
    
    let ingredients = Object.keys(mapIngredientToDishes);
    
    console.log("The ingredients list Object.keys(mapIngredientToDishes) is: ");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(ingredients));
    
    ingredients.sort();
    
    console.log("The SORTED ingredients list after .sort() is: ");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(ingredients));
    
    ingredients = ingredients.filter(function(ingredient) {
        const dishes = mapIngredientToDishes[ingredient];
        const keepIt = dishes.length > 1;

        console.log("  ingredient " + ingredient + " is used in " + dishes.length + " dish(es); keep it? " + keepIt);

        return keepIt;
    });
    
    console.log("The SORTED and FILTERED ingredients list after .filter() is: ");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(ingredients));
    
    const result = ingredients.map(function(ingredient) {
        const dishes = mapIngredientToDishes[ingredient];
        dishes.sort();
        const arr = [ingredient];
        console.log("  concatenate " + JSON.stringify(arr) + " with " + JSON.stringify(dishes));
        return arr.concat(dishes);
    });

    return result;
}

// Example run
const dishes = [["Salad", "Tomato", "Cucumber", "Salad", "Sauce"],["Pizza", "Tomato", "Sausage", "Sauce", "Dough"],["Quesadilla", "Chicken", "Cheese", "Sauce"],["Sandwich", "Salad", "Bread", "Tomato", "Cheese"]]
const result = solution(dishes);
console.log("Final result:");
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That explains alot. I will try to understand it by breaking it down. your explanation is very good.